# VBA convert time on Number

Tags: excel, vba

I need to convert my time to Number. i need it because letter i'm going to divide this dates by yourself to calculate % (agent productive time ).

I tried something like this

```
'cells(2,3) = 22:12:2

cells(2,3) / (60*60*1000)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Time is already a number in Excel. What units do you need it in?

Comment: I need to calculate how many % of the second number is the prime number.

Comment: Maybe provide sample data and the expected output to add clarity.

Comment: Sure    my input : number a = 78:19:41 number b = 74:23:58 output = 94,98%

Comment: So basically: `=b/a`? Number format as percentage. It will work fine if you replace those variables with a cell's reference.

Comment: i have tried it earlie but i was getting error ("Type mismatch")

Comment: I tried reference by Cells(2,4)/Cells(2,3) It works on other number for example cells (2,4) = 3, Cells(2,3) = 5. Unfortunately doesn't on date

Comment: Are you sure your date is a number and not text that looks like a date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this:

```vb
a = "78:19:41"
b = "74:23:58"
ta = (Split(a, ":")(0) / 24) + TimeValue("00:" & Split(a, ":", 2)(1))
tb = (Split(b, ":")(0) / 24) + TimeValue("00:" & Split(b, ":", 2)(1))

p = tb / ta * 100
p -> 94.9844138434859
```

Comment: Great! Then please mark as answered.

Comment: stack have informed  me.If i don't have at least 15 reputation, i can't vote, but they will record that

Comment: It worked. Happy New Year!